# fsockopen always Operation timed out

Tags: php, sockets, email, smtp

When I want to connect to port 25 with the fsockopen function, I get Connection refused or Operation timed out error. I get the same error on a hosting I tried for the first time. I'm getting the same error on different hostings at the same time. How can I solve it?

```
$mxSocket = @fsockopen($mxHost, 25, $errno, $errStr, 2);
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there's a firewall blocking you. Some residential ISPs only allow you to connect to their mail relay, to prevent you from spamming.

Comment: When I connect from the phone internet, it works for all servers at once. In fact, all the servers were working at first, and after turning the computer off and on, all of them stopped working at the same time.